# PHP MySQL - Data Update by Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie to PHP. I have data in array like :

```
Array ( [0] => Mr. ABC [1] => Ms. XYZ )
```

And am trying to update 2 rows having same id in MySQL. My codes are :

```
$n = count($p_title);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
{                   
    $query=("UPDATE table SET p_title='$p_title[$i]' WHERE q_no='$q_no'");
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

On update both the rows get data "Ms. XYZ". Where I am mistaking :(.

Comment: Of course *both* rows are being updated, in every loop iteration you update *all* rows `WHERE q_no='$q_no'`.  How do you know which row you want to have which value?  How can "2 rows have [the] same id"?  How would you tell them apart?

Comment: You need something unique for each row (i.e. unique IDs for rows) to update data to the relevant one.

Comment: Your database shema pls. What is the primary key? and do not even think of saying you do not have one!

Comment: where variable `$q_no` came from? show us more code

Comment: @inetphantom : ppid is the primary key.

Comment: @Alex : `$p_title` - gets jason_stringfy data in array, which needs to be updated based on `q_no` - that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't differenciate the rows by ID, you might give this a try

```
WHERE q_no='$q_no' LIMIT 1,$i
```

Limit consists of:

- The numbers of rows effected
- The number of row the query should start on

It's not clean solution ... it might work thought

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: This *might* work, but without an `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee that the rows are in the order you expect.

Comment: @Michael Bausano : `q_no='$q_no' LIMIT 1,$i` gives SQL Syntax error. :(

Comment: @Vikram Oh, then you have to `LIMIT 1,".$i."` put the variable into string.
@RocketHazmat yeah that's true, it's not fine solution and if possible, there should be an unique ID in database. but i tried to bring solution that would work with the given options. it might be used as a different point of view on the problem, and even tho it's not "clean", it _might_ work as a solution.

Comment: @MichaelBausano : nah its not working. Same SQL syntax error. Will bang head again on it today :( . Thanks everybody.